# HG clone using TortoiseHg throws “getaddrinfo failed” error on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, clone, mercurial, tortoise-hg

I have Windows XP installed in my system. I have installed `tortoisehg-2.10-hg-2.8-x86.msi`. I have checkpoint vpn1-secuRemote installed on my system. I am trying to clone a project. But when I clone a project I get the following error

```
URLError: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed [command returned code 255 Tue Jul 01 22:40:02 2014]
```

The same worked when I connect from my office. The `mercurial.ini` is as follows

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog
[ui]
username = avinash
verbose = True
```

Since it is Windows XP I have placed my `mercurial.ini` in `C:\Documents and Settings\avinash\mercurial.ini`.

I have gone through several links on Stack Overflow. But was not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo failed` means (as written) "XP's dens resolver can't convert name of host for remote repository into it's IP address"

- Check your DNS-settings
- Check your firewall settings (connections on remote 53 port /TCP|UDP/ must be enabled, better - globally)

You can get more detailed report, if you'll clone from console with `-v --debug` options

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error could be a wrong proxy configuration.

On Windows, TortoiseHg reads the proxy configuration from the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`, not from the Internet Options dialog! So you have to set (or clear) these variables accordingly in the Advanced System Properties dialog found under Control Panel -> System and Security -> System.